# call local variable of a function in another function

Tags: python-2.7

I have created a setting window in python where i have a few path settings which has to be one time setting.Here is the sample demo code,

```
import wx
import os
class SettingWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
        panel= wx.Panel(self,-1)
        font = wx.Font(8, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        field1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(120,25),size=(170,20))
        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        field1_sz=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        field2_sz=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        field1_lbl=wx.StaticText(panel,-1, label='Repo URL path:', pos=(25, 25))
        field1_lbl.SetFont(font)
        field1_sz.AddSpacer(50)
        field1_sz.Add(field1_lbl)
        field1_sz.AddSpacer(5) # put 5px of space between
        field1_sz.Add(field1)
        field1_sz.AddSpacer(50)

        vsizer.AddSpacer(50)
        vsizer.Add(field1_sz)
        vsizer.AddSpacer(15)
        vsizer.Add(field2_sz)
        vsizer.AddSpacer(50)

        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Browse',pos=(300,25),size=(60,20))
        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.opendir)

    def opendir(self, event):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_NEW_DIR_BUTTON)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            field1.SetValue("%s",dlg.GetPath())

        dlg.Destroy()




class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame= SettingWindow(None,-1,'Setting Window')
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True
app= MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

I want to display the path which i get from opendir in textCtrl.I am finding an error like below,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PROJECT\SettingWindow.py", line 58, in opendir
    return (field1)
NameError: global name 'field1' is not defined

Comment: can anyone please let me know how to make the text field disable when checked on checkbox and how to pass the value(in above case is the path) in the checkbox to the other class where the function takes that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use self.field1 instead of variable field1:

```
self.field1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,pos=(120,25),size=(170,20))

self.field1.SetValue(dlg.GetPath())
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It worked.How would i make the selected path default using checkbox?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know what you mean. Can you describe it for more detail?

Comment: According to the above code, i have a directory path in field1. Now i need to make it default making the TextCtrl disable by clicking on the checkbox and pass the input path to other class.

Answer (score 1):

This code works to make the TextCtrl field hidden when clicked on the checkbox

```
def OnCheckBox(self,event):
    if self.checkbox.Value==False:
        self.field.Enable(True)
    else:
        self.field.Enable(False)
```